# SQL query to get max homeruns for each year

Tags: sql

In the database we have the table `batter`, which contains a record for each batter each year they played as well as their game stats for that year. How would I write a query to select each player that has the max number of homeruns out of all players?

I've been trying with

```
SELECT *
FROM master
WHERE batting.HR = (
    SELECT MAX(batting.HR)
    FROM batting
)
```

But have had no luck. How could I do this?

Comment: mysql and sql server are two different platforms...don't tag with both.

Comment: You have tags for both Sql Server and MySql. Those are two different databases, and I'd do this very differently depending on which one you're using. Namely, Sql Server supports APPLY, while MySql does not.

Comment: Curious why you think you need to select from 'master' here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM batter b
INNER JOIN (
   select year, Max(hr) as MaxHR
   from batter
    group by year
) y on b.year = y.year and b.HR = y.MaxHR
```

Note this is vulnerable to two players tying. It's not clear what you want to see in that case.

Comment: AH, you included year and I missed that.  Deleting my answer, defer to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your RDBMS supports [SQL2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2003), you can use a window function:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        batter,
        year,
        hr,
        MAX(hr) OVER (PARTITION BY year) AS year_best_hr
    FROM batting
)
WHERE hr = year_best_hr
```